# C++ dynamic threads

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, assembly, access-violation

I allocated some space, wrote some asm and tried to start a thread at that point.
But I keep getting an access violation. Its suppose to push four 0s and call the messageboxa function. But right at the area address it gets a access violation.
How can I get it to run like normal code?

```
void test2()
{
    byte* area;
    HANDLE process;

    area = new byte[1024];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        area[i] = 0;

    memmove((char*)area, "\x6a\x00\x6a\x00\x6a\x00\x6a\x00\xE8", 9);

    *(DWORD*)&area[9] = ((DWORD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("User32.dll"), "MessageBoxA") - (DWORD)&area[9] - 4);

    memmove((char*)&area[13], "\x33\xc0\xc3", 3);

    VirtualProtect(area, 17, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, 0);

    CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)area, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

here's a screen shot of the disassembly
http://screensnapr.com/v/P33NsH.png

Comment: Try `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` perhaps.

Comment: Can you get a stack trace from the point where you get the access violation? Is it in the assembly code, or is it at the point that you call CreateThread?

Comment: Its from the address of the first push, not from the call to create the thread

Comment: What is the return value from `VirtualProtect`? If it is zero, what is the return value of `GetLastError`?

Comment: @Rob virtual protect fails and the last error is ERROR_NOACCESS 998

Comment: Back in the good old days, malware authors could write their own exploits without recourse to Stack Overflow. Halcyon days indeed.

Comment: I found this thread while looking for exactly the same issue. It is a bit disappointing to be suspected for doing evil all the time (not just on SO), just because one uses some not-so-common OS services... There are plenty of good reasons to use VirtualProtect(...PAGE_EXECUTE...). For example: accelerating execution with a JIT compiler (http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html), hardening applications via binary translation (http://nebelwelt.net/projects/libdetox/), or sandboxing untrusted plugins for a browser (http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VirtualProtect()` call doesn't do anything in this case: it just fails since it expects the 4th parameter to be a valid pointer to a memory area which receives the previous access protection flags (so you can restore it later).  So, the CPU refuses to execute this page and you get the GPF at the very first instruction.

You also need to use `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` for the flag, otherwise the first heap operation (even read access to any other variable in the heap, which happens to touch the same page) will generate GPF.  Alternatively, use `VirtualAlloc()`, instead of allocating on the heap.

Note, I didn't check the rest of the code, so there might be some other issues with it.  Also note that this is not the way to write assembly, unless you're writing an exploit (messing with `VirtualProtect()` is a sure sign of that).  Here's to hoping that I'm wrong in my assumption about the exploit.

Comment: Its not an exploit, but rather a shortcut function that should make other things faster for me. Also thanks, I did figure out it was the last parameter acting up.